# Why doesn't setting frame src by js show the display source?

Tags: javascript, css, html, scripting

Based on a JS condition, I want either of the 2 things to happen;

1. Either to show a frame on page 

   OR
2. Show a link "Show pdf" on page..
   Show pdf

Now while I know how to do a Show/Hide based on the JS condition, my question is
In case 2nd condition is satisfied, not only do I want to hide the frame thing, BUT ensure that it is not loaded in the background as well...
I think using show/hide will not stop it from loading the pdf in the background..
So my question is how can I acheive that using Javascript?

**********Here is what I am trying**********

```
if(isiPad) 
        {     
        $('#content').attr('src','ipad_frame.html'); 
        } 
        else 
        {     
        $('#content').attr('src','xyz.pdf'); 
        }
```

And in the html, I have

```
 <frame src="#" title="Content Frame" name="content" id="content" />
```

Will this work fine? For some reasons, I just tested it and even though it goes in the if/else part, it does not show the relevant content..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add the elements dynamically in script to a container element? Something like (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
if(condition)
{
    $('#container').html('<html for frame>');
}
else
{
    $('#container').html('<html for pdf>');
}
```

This will ensure only the item that you want to load is loaded.

Comment: woops.. and *that* is what happens when you type code late night directly into reply boxes ;)

Comment: Is it reasonable to import jQuery for something so simple?

Comment: In short, sure.. Otherwise, just use the native javascript element functions

Comment: Thx a lot...No problems at all with  the syntax issues..Also jQuery is fine with me..My only question is when we say if..else, only one condition can be satisfied at a time..but since one of those will have the "pdf" reference (<frame src='xyz.pdf'), will this approach ensure that the pdf will be loaded only in case that condition is satisfied and not otherwise...

Comment: @hmthr: The PDF will only be loaded once the elements have been added to the DOM. So no, it will not be loaded if the condition is not met.

Comment: Cool..Just one last question before I close and accept this..I have added code in my original question..Could you please verify if it will work fine ?

Comment: @hmthr: yep, that should be fine. to double-check for yourself, kick it off in FF (or chrome) and watch the net tab. your browser should *only* be issuing requests for whichever item you set to the `src` attribute.

Comment: Hey..Even though I have accepted the answer now..for some reason the JS works fine, but the actual content does not get displayed...e.g. Even if $('#content').attr('src','xyz.pdf'); is executed, the page does not display the pdf..I think page needs to be refreshed or something after setting the src attribute..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than show/hide, you could use the DOM to modify the contents of the page:

```
<div id="frameWillBeHere">

</div>

<script language="javascript">

var f = document.getElementById('frameWillBeHere');

if (whatever) {
   f.innerHTML = '<iframe>pdf file</iframe>';
}
else {
   f.innerHTML = 'something else';
}

</script>
```

You can also make that script respond to an event, so that the frame will appear when needed. There is some work to do so that the frame appearing in your page doesn't completely break your layout.

Comment: Thx a lot..But again the question is while f.innerHTML is set, the actual content does not get displayed...Not sure if I need to call the function on a particular event ?

Comment: Just to add, there is a problem in IE browser i.e. following works document.getElementById('content2').contentWindow.location = 'http://www.google.com'; 
But a local html call does not work i.e .document.getElementById('content2').contentWindow.location = 'ipad_frame.html';